# Override Swing Nimbus L&F primary color per component instance

Tags: java, swing, nimbus

i’m trying to override the “nimbusBase” color for specific instance of JButton/JTabbedPane with no luck.
    only the specific attributes of the component e.g. “Button.background”, are working.
    any idea?

```
UIDefaults dialogTheme = new UIDefaults();
// dialogTheme.put(“nimbusBase”, Color.orange);
// dialogTheme.put("nimbusBlueGrey", Color.blue);
dialogTheme.put("Button.background", Color.yellow);
JButton dialogButton = new JButton("North");
dialogButton.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults", true);
dialogButton.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", dialogTheme);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can put the Color to the `LookAndFeelDefaults` for all Components "nimbusBase"

```
UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();
defaults.put("nimbusBase", new ColorUIResource(210, 0, 210));
```

Or to a specific Component as you wrote it. Perhaps with update the componentTreeUI.

```
...
dialogTheme.put("Button.background", new ColorUIResource(0, 0, 210));
...
dialogButton.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", dialogTheme);
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(dialogButton);
```

I never override `"nimbusBase"` for a specific Component.

I found a nice Nimbus Theme Creator, which can show the effect of changing a [Nimbus Default Color](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html) to all Components: http://aephyr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk

**EDIT**

You can 'copy' the Painter, modify them and set them via UIDefaults:

Example GUI with an nimbusOrange JTabbedPane and a normal one.
[image]

```
public class Example {

    static public void main( String[] s ) throws Exception {
        for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }

        EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.getContentPane().setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
                frame.setBounds( 50, 50, 600, 600 );
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

                JTabbedPane pane = new JTabbedPane();
                pane.addTab( "Lorem", new JLabel("Lorem") );
                pane.addTab( "Ipsum", new JLabel("Ipsum") );
                pane.addTab( "Dolor", new JLabel("Dolor") );
                pane.addTab( "Sit", new JLabel("Sit") );
                pane.addTab( "Amet", new JLabel("Amet") );

                UIDefaults dialogTheme = new UIDefaults();
                dialogTheme.put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Enabled].backgroundPainter", new Painter(Painter.BACKGROUND_ENABLED));
                dialogTheme.put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Disabled].backgroundPainter", new Painter(Painter.BACKGROUND_DISABLED));
                dialogTheme.put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Enabled+MouseOver].backgroundPainter", new Painter(Painter.BACKGROUND_ENABLED_MOUSEOVER));
                dialogTheme.put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Enabled+Pressed].backgroundPainter", new Painter(Painter.BACKGROUND_ENABLED_PRESSED));
                dialogTheme.put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Selected].backgroundPainter", new Painter(Painter.BACKGROUND_SELECTED));
                dialogTheme.put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Disabled+Selected].backgroundPainter", new Painter(Painter.BACKGROUND_SELECTED_DISABLED));
                dialogTheme.put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Focused+Selected].backgroundPainter", new Painter(Painter.BACKGROUND_SELECTED_FOCUSED));
                dialogTheme.put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[MouseOver+Selected].backgroundPainter", new Painter(Painter.BACKGROUND_SELECTED_MOUSEOVER));
                dialogTheme.put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Focused+MouseOver+Selected].backgroundPainter", new Painter(Painter.BACKGROUND_SELECTED_MOUSEOVER_FOCUSED));
                dialogTheme.put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Pressed+Selected].backgroundPainter", new Painter(Painter.BACKGROUND_SELECTED_PRESSED));
                dialogTheme.put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTab[Focused+Pressed+Selected].backgroundPainter", new Painter(Painter.BACKGROUND_SELECTED_PRESSED_FOCUSED));
                dialogTheme.put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTabArea[Disabled].backgroundPainter", new AreaPainter(AreaPainter.BACKGROUND_DISABLED));
                dialogTheme.put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTabArea[Enabled+MouseOver].backgroundPainter", new AreaPainter(AreaPainter.BACKGROUND_ENABLED_MOUSEOVER));
                dialogTheme.put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTabArea[Enabled+Pressed].backgroundPainter", new AreaPainter(AreaPainter.BACKGROUND_ENABLED_PRESSED));
                dialogTheme.put("TabbedPane:TabbedPaneTabArea[Enabled].backgroundPainter", new AreaPainter(AreaPainter.BACKGROUND_ENABLED));
                pane.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults", Boolean.TRUE);
                pane.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", dialogTheme);

                JTabbedPane secondPane = new JTabbedPane();
                secondPane.addTab( "Lorem", new JLabel("Lorem") );
                secondPane.addTab( "Ipsum", new JLabel("Ipsum") );
                secondPane.addTab( "Dolor", new JLabel("Dolor") );
                secondPane.addTab( "Sit", new JLabel("Sit") );
                secondPane.addTab( "Amet", new JLabel("Amet") );

                frame.getContentPane().setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
                frame.getContentPane().add( pane, BorderLayout.NORTH );
                frame.getContentPane().add( secondPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
                frame.setVisible( true );
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Painter class with nimbusOrange**
**NOTE:** I removed the paint methods in this Painter example. Because this code was to long. Just add them via copy&past from `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.TabbedPaneTabbedPaneTabPainter`.

```
/*
 * TabbedPaneTabbedPaneTabPainter.java %E%
 *
 * Copyright 2007 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * SUN PROPRIETARY/CONFIDENTIAL. Use is subject to license terms.
 */

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.AbstractRegionPainter;

/**
 */
public final class Painter extends AbstractRegionPainter {
    //package private integers representing the available states that
    //this painter will paint. These are used when creating a new instance
    //of TabbedPaneTabbedPaneTabPainter to determine which region/state is being painted
    //by that instance.
    static final int BACKGROUND_ENABLED = 1;
    static final int BACKGROUND_ENABLED_MOUSEOVER = 2;
    static final int BACKGROUND_ENABLED_PRESSED = 3;
    static final int BACKGROUND_DISABLED = 4;
    static final int BACKGROUND_SELECTED_DISABLED = 5;
    static final int BACKGROUND_SELECTED = 6;
    static final int BACKGROUND_SELECTED_MOUSEOVER = 7;
    static final int BACKGROUND_SELECTED_PRESSED = 8;
    static final int BACKGROUND_SELECTED_FOCUSED = 9;
    static final int BACKGROUND_SELECTED_MOUSEOVER_FOCUSED = 10;
    static final int BACKGROUND_SELECTED_PRESSED_FOCUSED = 11;


    private int state; //refers to one of the static final ints above
    private PaintContext ctx;

    //the following 4 variables are reused during the painting code of the layers
    private Path2D path = new Path2D.Float();
    private Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, 0, 0);
    private RoundRectangle2D roundRect = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    private Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Float(0, 0, 0, 0);

    //All Colors used for painting are stored here. Ideally, only those colors being used
    //by a particular instance of TabbedPaneTabbedPaneTabPainter would be created. For the moment at least,
    //however, all are created for each instance.
    private Color color1 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.032459438f, -0.55535716f, -0.109803945f, 0);
    private Color color2 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.08801502f, 0.3642857f, -0.4784314f, 0);
    private Color color3 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.08801502f, -0.63174605f, 0.43921566f, 0);
    private Color color4 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.05468172f, -0.6145278f, 0.37647057f, 0);
    private Color color5 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.032459438f, -0.5953556f, 0.32549018f, 0);
    private Color color6 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.032459438f, -0.54616207f, -0.02352941f, 0);
    private Color color7 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.08801502f, -0.6317773f, 0.4470588f, 0);
    private Color color8 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.021348298f, -0.61547136f, 0.41960782f, 0);
    private Color color9 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.032459438f, -0.5985242f, 0.39999998f, 0);
    private Color color10 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.08801502f, 0.3642857f, -0.52156866f, 0);
    private Color color11 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.027408898f, -0.5847884f, 0.2980392f, 0);
    private Color color12 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.035931647f, -0.5553123f, 0.23137254f, 0);
    private Color color13 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.029681683f, -0.5281874f, 0.18039215f, 0);
    private Color color14 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.03801495f, -0.5456242f, 0.3215686f, 0);
    private Color color15 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.032459438f, -0.59181184f, 0.25490195f, 0);
    private Color color16 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.05468172f, -0.58308274f, 0.19607842f, 0);
    private Color color17 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.046348333f, -0.6006266f, 0.34509802f, 0);
    private Color color18 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.046348333f, -0.60015875f, 0.3333333f, 0);
    private Color color19 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.004681647f, -0.6197143f, 0.43137252f, 0);
    private Color color20 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 7.13408E-4f, -0.543609f, 0.34509802f, 0);
    private Color color21 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", -0.0020751357f, -0.45610264f, 0.2588235f, 0);
    private Color color22 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 5.1498413E-4f, -0.43866998f, 0.24705881f, 0);
    private Color color23 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 5.1498413E-4f, -0.44879842f, 0.29019606f, 0);
    private Color color24 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 5.1498413E-4f, -0.08776909f, -0.2627451f, 0);
    private Color color25 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.06332368f, 0.3642857f, -0.4431373f, 0);
    private Color color26 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.004681647f, -0.6198413f, 0.43921566f, 0);
    private Color color27 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", -0.0022627711f, -0.5335866f, 0.372549f, 0);
    private Color color28 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", -0.0017285943f, -0.4608264f, 0.32549018f, 0);
    private Color color29 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 5.1498413E-4f, -0.4555341f, 0.3215686f, 0);
    private Color color30 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 5.1498413E-4f, -0.46404046f, 0.36470586f, 0);
    private Color color31 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", -0.57865167f, -0.6357143f, -0.54901963f, 0);
    private Color color32 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", -4.2033195E-4f, -0.38050595f, 0.20392156f, 0);
    private Color color33 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.0013483167f, -0.16401619f, 0.0745098f, 0);
    private Color color34 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", -0.0010001659f, -0.01599598f, 0.007843137f, 0);
    private Color color35 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0);
    private Color color36 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.0018727183f, -0.038398862f, 0.035294116f, 0);
    private Color color37 = decodeColor("nimbusRed", 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0);


    //Array of current component colors, updated in each paint call
    private Object[] componentColors;

    public Painter(int state) {
        super();
        this.state = state;
        Insets insets = null;
        switch( state ) {
            case BACKGROUND_ENABLED:                   insets = new Insets(7, 7, 1, 7); break;
            case BACKGROUND_ENABLED_MOUSEOVER:         insets = new Insets(7, 7, 1, 7); break;
            case BACKGROUND_ENABLED_PRESSED:           insets = new Insets(7, 6, 1, 7); break;
            case BACKGROUND_DISABLED:                  insets = new Insets(6, 7, 1, 7); break;
            case BACKGROUND_SELECTED_DISABLED:         insets = new Insets(7, 7, 0, 7); break;
            case BACKGROUND_SELECTED:                  insets = new Insets(7, 7, 0, 7); break;
            case BACKGROUND_SELECTED_MOUSEOVER:        insets = new Insets(7, 9, 0, 9); break;
            case BACKGROUND_SELECTED_PRESSED:          insets = new Insets(7, 9, 0, 9); break;
            case BACKGROUND_SELECTED_FOCUSED:          insets = new Insets(7, 7, 3, 7); break;
            case BACKGROUND_SELECTED_MOUSEOVER_FOCUSED:insets = new Insets(7, 9, 3, 9); break;
            case BACKGROUND_SELECTED_PRESSED_FOCUSED:  insets = new Insets(7, 9, 3, 9); break;
        }
        this.ctx = new AbstractRegionPainter.PaintContext(insets, new Dimension( 10  , 20 ), false );
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPaint(Graphics2D g, JComponent c, int width, int height, Object[] extendedCacheKeys) {
        //populate componentColors array with colors calculated in getExtendedCacheKeys call
        componentColors = extendedCacheKeys;
        //generate this entire method. Each state/bg/fg/border combo that has
        //been painted gets its own KEY and paint method.
        switch(state) {
            case BACKGROUND_ENABLED: paintBackgroundEnabled(g); break;
            case BACKGROUND_ENABLED_MOUSEOVER: paintBackgroundEnabledAndMouseOver(g); break;
            case BACKGROUND_ENABLED_PRESSED: paintBackgroundEnabledAndPressed(g); break;
            case BACKGROUND_DISABLED: paintBackgroundDisabled(g); break;
            case BACKGROUND_SELECTED_DISABLED: paintBackgroundSelectedAndDisabled(g); break;
            case BACKGROUND_SELECTED: paintBackgroundSelected(g); break;
            case BACKGROUND_SELECTED_MOUSEOVER: paintBackgroundSelectedAndMouseOver(g); break;
            case BACKGROUND_SELECTED_PRESSED: paintBackgroundSelectedAndPressed(g); break;
            case BACKGROUND_SELECTED_FOCUSED: paintBackgroundSelectedAndFocused(g); break;
            case BACKGROUND_SELECTED_MOUSEOVER_FOCUSED: paintBackgroundSelectedAndMouseOverAndFocused(g); break;
            case BACKGROUND_SELECTED_PRESSED_FOCUSED: paintBackgroundSelectedAndPressedAndFocused(g); break;

        }
    }



    @Override
    protected final PaintContext getPaintContext() {
        return ctx;
    }

    // ... paintBackgroundEnabled( ...
    // ...
}
```

**AreaPainter with numbusOrange**

```
/*
 * TabbedPaneTabbedPaneTabAreaPainter.java %E%
 *
 * Copyright 2007 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * SUN PROPRIETARY/CONFIDENTIAL. Use is subject to license terms.
 */

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.PaintContext;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.AbstractRegionPainter;

/**
 */
public final class AreaPainter extends AbstractRegionPainter {
    //package private integers representing the available states that
    //this painter will paint. These are used when creating a new instance
    //of TabbedPaneTabbedPaneTabAreaPainter to determine which region/state is being painted
    //by that instance.
    static final int BACKGROUND_ENABLED = 1;
    static final int BACKGROUND_DISABLED = 2;
    static final int BACKGROUND_ENABLED_MOUSEOVER = 3;
    static final int BACKGROUND_ENABLED_PRESSED = 4;


    private int state; //refers to one of the static final ints above
    private PaintContext ctx;

    //the following 4 variables are reused during the painting code of the layers
    private Path2D path = new Path2D.Float();
    private Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, 0, 0);
    private RoundRectangle2D roundRect = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    private Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Float(0, 0, 0, 0);

    //All Colors used for painting are stored here. Ideally, only those colors being used
    //by a particular instance of TabbedPaneTabbedPaneTabAreaPainter would be created. For the moment at least,
    //however, all are created for each instance.
    private Color color1 = new Color(255, 200, 0, 255);
    private Color color2 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.08801502f, 0.3642857f, -0.4784314f, 0);
    private Color color3 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 5.1498413E-4f, -0.45471883f, 0.31764704f, 0);
    private Color color4 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 5.1498413E-4f, -0.4633005f, 0.3607843f, 0);
    private Color color5 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.05468172f, -0.58308274f, 0.19607842f, 0);
    private Color color6 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", -0.57865167f, -0.6357143f, -0.54901963f, 0);
    private Color color7 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 5.1498413E-4f, -0.4690476f, 0.39215684f, 0);
    private Color color8 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 5.1498413E-4f, -0.47635174f, 0.4352941f, 0);
    private Color color9 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.0f, -0.05401492f, 0.05098039f, 0);
    private Color color10 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.0f, -0.09303135f, 0.09411764f, 0);


    //Array of current component colors, updated in each paint call
    private Object[] componentColors;

    public AreaPainter(int state) {
        super();
        this.state = state;
        this.ctx = new AbstractRegionPainter.PaintContext(new Insets(0, 5, 6, 5), new Dimension(5, 24), false );

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPaint(Graphics2D g, JComponent c, int width, int height, Object[] extendedCacheKeys) {
        //populate componentColors array with colors calculated in getExtendedCacheKeys call
        componentColors = extendedCacheKeys;
        //generate this entire method. Each state/bg/fg/border combo that has
        //been painted gets its own KEY and paint method.
        switch(state) {
            case BACKGROUND_ENABLED: paintBackgroundEnabled(g); break;
            case BACKGROUND_DISABLED: paintBackgroundDisabled(g); break;
            case BACKGROUND_ENABLED_MOUSEOVER: paintBackgroundEnabledAndMouseOver(g); break;
            case BACKGROUND_ENABLED_PRESSED: paintBackgroundEnabledAndPressed(g); break;

        }
    }



    @Override
    protected final PaintContext getPaintContext() {
        return ctx;
    }

    private void paintBackgroundEnabled(Graphics2D g) {
        rect = decodeRect1();
        g.setPaint(color1);
        g.fill(rect);
        rect = decodeRect2();
        g.setPaint(decodeGradient1(rect));
        g.fill(rect);

    }

    private void paintBackgroundDisabled(Graphics2D g) {
        rect = decodeRect2();
        g.setPaint(decodeGradient2(rect));
        g.fill(rect);

    }

    private void paintBackgroundEnabledAndMouseOver(Graphics2D g) {
        rect = decodeRect2();
        g.setPaint(decodeGradient3(rect));
        g.fill(rect);

    }

    private void paintBackgroundEnabledAndPressed(Graphics2D g) {
        rect = decodeRect2();
        g.setPaint(decodeGradient4(rect));
        g.fill(rect);

    }



    private Rectangle2D decodeRect1() {
            rect.setRect(decodeX(0.0f), //x
                         decodeY(1.0f), //y
                         decodeX(0.0f) - decodeX(0.0f), //width
                         decodeY(1.0f) - decodeY(1.0f)); //height
        return rect;
    }

    private Rectangle2D decodeRect2() {
            rect.setRect(decodeX(0.0f), //x
                         decodeY(2.1666667f), //y
                         decodeX(3.0f) - decodeX(0.0f), //width
                         decodeY(3.0f) - decodeY(2.1666667f)); //height
        return rect;
    }



    private Paint decodeGradient1(Shape s) {
        Rectangle2D bounds = s.getBounds2D();
        float x = (float)bounds.getX();
        float y = (float)bounds.getY();
        float w = (float)bounds.getWidth();
        float h = (float)bounds.getHeight();
        return decodeGradient((0.5f * w) + x, (0.0f * h) + y, (0.5f * w) + x, (1.0f * h) + y,
                new float[] { 0.08387097f,0.09677419f,0.10967742f,0.43709677f,0.7645161f,0.7758064f,0.7870968f },
                new Color[] { color2,
                            decodeColor(color2,color3,0.5f),
                            color3,
                            decodeColor(color3,color4,0.5f),
                            color4,
                            decodeColor(color4,color2,0.5f),
                            color2});
    }

    private Paint decodeGradient2(Shape s) {
        Rectangle2D bounds = s.getBounds2D();
        float x = (float)bounds.getX();
        float y = (float)bounds.getY();
        float w = (float)bounds.getWidth();
        float h = (float)bounds.getHeight();
        return decodeGradient((0.5f * w) + x, (0.0f * h) + y, (0.5f * w) + x, (1.0f * h) + y,
                new float[] { 0.08387097f,0.09677419f,0.10967742f,0.43709677f,0.7645161f,0.7758064f,0.7870968f },
                new Color[] { color5,
                            decodeColor(color5,color3,0.5f),
                            color3,
                            decodeColor(color3,color4,0.5f),
                            color4,
                            decodeColor(color4,color5,0.5f),
                            color5});
    }

    private Paint decodeGradient3(Shape s) {
        Rectangle2D bounds = s.getBounds2D();
        float x = (float)bounds.getX();
        float y = (float)bounds.getY();
        float w = (float)bounds.getWidth();
        float h = (float)bounds.getHeight();
        return decodeGradient((0.5f * w) + x, (0.0f * h) + y, (0.5f * w) + x, (1.0f * h) + y,
                new float[] { 0.08387097f,0.09677419f,0.10967742f,0.43709677f,0.7645161f,0.7758064f,0.7870968f },
                new Color[] { color6,
                            decodeColor(color6,color7,0.5f),
                            color7,
                            decodeColor(color7,color8,0.5f),
                            color8,
                            decodeColor(color8,color2,0.5f),
                            color2});
    }

    private Paint decodeGradient4(Shape s) {
        Rectangle2D bounds = s.getBounds2D();
        float x = (float)bounds.getX();
        float y = (float)bounds.getY();
        float w = (float)bounds.getWidth();
        float h = (float)bounds.getHeight();
        return decodeGradient((0.5f * w) + x, (0.0f * h) + y, (0.5f * w) + x, (1.0f * h) + y,
                new float[] { 0.08387097f,0.09677419f,0.10967742f,0.43709677f,0.7645161f,0.7758064f,0.7870968f },
                new Color[] { color2,
                            decodeColor(color2,color9,0.5f),
                            color9,
                            decodeColor(color9,color10,0.5f),
                            color10,
                            decodeColor(color10,color2,0.5f),
                            color2});
    }


}
```

Comment: i tried it before asking this question, and it didn't work. the reason i'm asking this question is because we want in our team to change the color of the tabbedPane to be orange.

Comment: i tried it before asking this question, and it didn't work. the reason i'm asking this question is because we want in our team to change the color of the tabbedPane to be orange, but ONLY for one instace which is in the main view of the application. we looked in the TabbedPaneTabbedPaneTabAreaPainter but this is not a public class so we cannot override it.any suggestions? note the that we want the same painter but with specific color.

Comment: Oh MAN! I've been trying to change colors for JProgressBar for ages, despite all answers given on several questions by respected @mKorbel, I was finally able to do it by COPY-PASTING-HACKING A NIMBUS PAINTER!!! How ugly is that?!
I'd like to open a bug in Nimbus: color names should also be part of the `Nimbus.Overrides` `UIDefaults`...

Comment: To override values for a specific component it's better to create a new instance of `UIDefaults`, I've had strange effects with overriding the global defaults returned by `UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults()`.

For example:

`Object[] uiDefaults = {
        "TextField.contentMargins", new Insets(0,0,0,0),
        "TextField[Enabled].borderPainter", new MyBorderPainter()
};
textComponent.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", new UIDefaults(uiDefaults));`