# Change the color of a tab in Nimbus

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Override Swing Nimbus L&F primary color per component instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922368/override-swing-nimbus-lf-primary-color-per-component-instance)

How can I change the default color of tab  in Nimbus PLAF?

When the tab is selected the color will be Orange and the unselected tab should be grey color.
Please give me some example with code.

Comment: Not all Look & Feels support changing the tab color. My guess is, Nimbues is one of them.

Comment: Not very easy here is an example I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922368/override-swing-nimbus-lf-primary-color-per-component-instance

Answer (score 1):

I just Google for it 
see this maybe can help
http://www.jasperpotts.com/blog/2008/08/nimbus-uimanager-uidefaults/