# How to Change JProgressbar Bar color within table cell Using Nimbus Look And Feel

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar, tablecellrenderer, nimbus

My problem is that I have table which one of the columns have ProgressBars within table cells, I would like dynamically change ProgressBar's Bar color dynamically based on row and column number, however I cannot achive it. Also there are limitations of Nimbus too.
I have to override Nimbus UI Defaults per component based. So if I want to dynamically change a cell's bar color, how could I achieve it without changing cell text color?

```
 public class ProgressRenderer extends JProgressBar implements TableCellRenderer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ProgressRenderer(int min, int max) {
        super(min, max);
        this.setStringPainted(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        this.setValue((Integer) value);
        UIDefaults defaults = new UIDefaults();
        defaults.put("ProgressBar[Enabled].foregroundPainter", new MyPainter(Color.RED));
       defaults.put("ProgressBar[Enabled+Finished].foregroundPainter", new MyPainter(Color.RED));

              putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults", Boolean.TRUE);
     putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", defaults);
        return this;
    }

    class MyPainter implements Painter<JProgressBar> {

        private final Color color;

        public MyPainter(Color c1) {
            this.color = c1;
        }
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics2D gd, JProgressBar t, int width, int height) {
            gd.setColor(color);
            gd.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        }
    }         
}
```

Above is my code snippet, which I use TableCellRenderer.

Answer (score 2):

Something like that? ;)

[image: Different JProgressBar on JTable cells]

The problem you have is that it is **extremely** painful to override Nimbus' default colors for a specific component instance (see a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922368/override-swing-nimbus-lf-primary-color-per-component-instance)).

Most of Nimbus painters are defining around 50 different colors, derived from one or two basic ones (the `nimbusBlueGrey` and famous `nimbusOrange`). The best way would have been to override them in the `UIDefaults` found in `Nimbus.Override` property of the component you want to change, but it's not what they did (I'd like to open a bug on that ;), no seriously!).

I've been trying to achieve the exact same thing and was finally able to by ... (close your eyes) copy-pasting and hacking the `javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.ProgressBarPainter` class into my own code! Why? Because that class is private to the package and cannot be overriden (which would have been a bit cleaner...).
As much as I *hate* to do that, it worked...

Here is how to modify it (I won't post the whole code as it's way too big and not that interesting):

1. Start by adding the following methods after the `ProgressBarPainter()` constructor. (they are basically a copy-paste of what you can find following the `decodeColor()` method down to `AbstractRegionPainter` then `NimbusLookAndFeel` then `NimbusDefaults.getDerivedColor()` and finally `DerivedColor.rederiveColor()`):

   ```
   private float clamp(float v) {
       if (v < 0.0f)
           return 0.0f;
       if (v > 1.0f)
           return 1.0f;
       return v;
   }

   private int clamp(int v) {
       if (v < 0)
           return 0;
       if (v > 255)
           return 255;
       return v;
   }

       // Got from javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.DerivedColor.rederiveColor()
   private Color decodeColor(Color src, float hOffset, float sOffset, float bOffset, int aOffset) {
       float[] tmp = Color.RGBtoHSB(src.getRed(), src.getGreen(), src.getBlue(), null);
       tmp[0] = clamp(tmp[0] + hOffset);
       tmp[1] = clamp(tmp[1] + sOffset);
       tmp[2] = clamp(tmp[2] + bOffset);
       int alpha = clamp(src.getAlpha() + aOffset);
       return new Color((Color.HSBtoRGB(tmp[0], tmp[1], tmp[2]) & 0xFFFFFF) | (alpha << 24), true);
   }
   ```
2. Copy-paste the code statically generating the 50 colors to a method you'll use to generate them dynamically, from the color you want:

From :

```
private Color color1 = decodeColor("nimbusBlueGrey", 0.0f, -0.04845735f, -0.17647058f, 0);
...
private Color color50 = decodeColor("nimbusOrange", 0.0014062226f, -0.77816474f, 0.12941176f, 0);
```

To:

```
private void initColors(Color foreground) {
    color1 = decodeColor("nimbusBlueGrey", 0.0f, -0.04845735f, -0.17647058f, 0);
    // ...
    color50 = decodeColor(foreground, 0.0014062226f, -0.77816474f, 0.12941176f, 0);
}
```

Note that we pass the color we want as a parameter and use it as a replacement of `nimbusOrange`, which seems to be the main color for progress bars. We try to stick to Nimbus' way of deriving colors.

And change the `ProgressBarPainter()` constructor to include the main color and generate them:

```
public ProgressBarPainter(int state, Color foreground) {
    super();
    this.state = state;
    this.ctx = new AbstractRegionPainter.PaintContext(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), new Dimension(29, 19), false);
    initColors(foreground); // Generates appropriate colors
}
```

You'll find how to initialize the `ctx` field in the source of `NimbusDefaults`. However, note that the enum `AbstractRegionPainter.PaintContext.CacheMode` is not visible from the tweaked class so you won't be able to use all the fancy features. Fortunately, there is a simpler constructor to `AbstractRegionPainter.PaintContext` that doesn't use it.
(In my case, I didn't need all of the different states so I used default values, but feel free to add any other parameter to cope with them).

And finally, the Graal! ;)
(I'm changing color according to the value that should be a percentage: `green` if more than 75%, `orange` if more than 50% and `red` otherwise).

```
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    int v = ((Integer)value).intValue();
    Color c;
    if (val >= 75)
        c = Color.GREEN;
    else if (val >= 50)
        c = Color.ORANGE;
    else
        c = Color.RED;
    setValue(v);
    UIDefaults defaults = new UIDefaults();
    ProgressBarPainter painter = new ProgressBarPainter(ProgressBarPainter.FOREGROUND_ENABLED, c);
    defaults.put("ProgressBar[Enabled].foregroundPainter", painter);
    putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", defaults);
    return this;
}
```

Now, let's "clean" that a little bit (as much as we can call that a "clean" work):

- delete the assignments for the `private Color colorXX` that use `nimbusOrange`, as they will be generated by the call to `initColors()`.
- keep the assignments for these which use `nimbusBlueGrey`, as we're not changing them, and do not include them in the `initColors()`. That leaves you with an `initColors()` generating 26 colors (17 to 28, 30, 33 to 44 and 50).
- if, like me, you only have a few colors to represent for all of you progress bars, pre-generate all `ProgressBarPainter`s you'll ever use and assign the correct one in `getTableCellRendererComponent()`
- (or in my case create three `private static JProgressBar red, orange, green` with appropriate overriden color painters and return them instead of `this` in `getTableCellRendererComponent()`)

Answer (score 2):

Alternately, what I ended up doing was extending `JPanel` and painting myself a progress bar with the color I want:

[image: Custom-drawn progress bar with colors]

```
public class ProgressBarCellRenderer extends JPanel implements TableCellRenderer {

    int val = 0;

    private static Paint generatePaint(Color c, int height) {
        return new LinearGradientPaint(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, (float)height, new float[]{0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f}, new Color[]{c.darker(), c.brighter(), c.darker()}, CycleMethod.REFLECT);
    }

    private static Paint greenPaint = generatePaint(Color.GREEN);
    private static Paint orangePaint = generatePaint(Color.ORANGE);
    private static Paint redPaint = generatePaint(Color.RED);

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        int x = 1;
        int y = 1;
        int w = getWidth()-2;
        int h = getHeight()-2;
        g2d.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g2d.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
        Paint backPaint;
        if (val >= 75)
            backPaint = greenPaint;
        else if (val >= 50)
            backPaint = orangePaint;
        else
            backPaint = redPaint;
        g2d.setPaint(backPaint);
        int wd = (int)Math.round(w * val / 100.0);
        g2d.fillRect(x, y, wd, h);
        g2d.draw3DRect(x, y, wd, h, true);
        // Draw some text here if you want
    }
}
```

Result looks good enough for me and I find it a lot cleaner (and efficient) than the "[Nimbus hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17359451/1098603)"!

Comment: maybe not good, required deepest look at it, but make required things, +1 for effort :-)

Comment: Yes, I got tired of searching about how to tweak Nimbus so I went for this quickly. If you see some obvious mistakes or improvements, feel free to edit! I'm into Swing for just a month now :)